# Handling instances of Processes in Camunda 8 Python

Tags: python, camunda, camunda-modeler

***context :***

I have created a BPMN  and also i have started the process using Python

***Problem***

Now the problems is all the script task gets executed right away the moment Token reaches to that task However i want to execute based on process execution key

so even though there are 3 process at the same stage

i can still target a particular instance of a process and complete its task

***Current Status***

The BPMN is as follows

[image]

**Code to create CLient and stuff**

```
from pyzeebe import create_insecure_channel
channel = create_insecure_channel(hostname="localhost", port=26500)
from pyzeebe import ZeebeClient, create_insecure_channel
client = ZeebeClient(channel)
```

**Code for starting the campnunda process**

```
process_instance_key = await client.run_process("process_qwerty",{"var1":"val1","var2":"val2"})
```

**Code for a Worker**

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
from pyzeebe import ZeebeTaskRouter
from pyzeebe import ZeebeWorker, create_insecure_channel,Job
import asyncio
import random
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

async def main():
    worker = ZeebeWorker(channel)
    router = ZeebeTaskRouter()
    
    async def exception_handler(exception: Exception, job: Job) -> None:
        await job.set_error_status(message= 'PropertyError', error_code='PropertyError') 

    @router.task(task_type="TimerValue")
    async def TimerValue(job:Job):
        print(dir(job))
        return {"timer_value":"P14D"}
    
    worker.include_router(router)
    await worker.work()

asyncio.run(main())
print("done")
```

**Problem Statement**

I don't want to complete a task of all instance i want to use the Job object to choose which task should be completed and which one should be kept in pending state

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to understand why you want it to work in this way. It smells like a questionable architecture. Maybe you can provide more context.There could be a use case for a message receive event somewhere.
Maybe you want to switch to a message send and receive pattern?

The worker can control how long a task stays locked and if it completes the task or not. If you don't want to complete the job, then you can skip the complete command and the task will get unlocked again after the lock times out. But then the question remains when you want to complete the job you skipped. The worker would keep picking it up after it gets unlocked.